# Unknown code added to XML file in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, virus, xml, bug

Can anybody explain to me the next issue please..

I have a XML file. When I open it (via ULR) in Edge it looks correct:

[image]

but when I open it (via URL) in Chrome, some unknown  code is added at the end:

[image]

this code is only in the browser tab, because if I open the source by Ctrl+U, evertything looks correct:

[image]

I saved the XML to computer and dropped it at Chrome tab - everything is ok and no additional code.

Is it some kind of Chrome XML viewer bug or virus? Please advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The way the it's obfuscated does look pretty nasty. Take a look at the  developer tools (F12) > sources tab, and see if you can find where it comes from. Make sure you look through the little `>>` dropdown and select content scripts as well (stuff from extensions usually). This is most likely from a chrome extension that puked out something as text into the xml viewer, but there's a good chance that extension doesn't need to be allowed to look at local files

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thank you! Checking

Comment: @Cpt.Whale yes, it was added by extenstion. Interesting that I was not able to open chrome://extensions, it redirected me to chrome://settings .. Since I had them on tool bar, I started to remove them one by one. I remove Adobe, Avast Prices and Crunchbase B2B, then checked XML view and it was OK. Also I can open chrome://extensions too. So what it was? :D bugged extension or some kind of virus?

Comment: well, my take is that the extension embedded javascript in any page the browser downloads. XML output isn't generally rendered like a webpage is (HTML is a form of XML, so rendering XML data as hypertext would not be what you want), so the scripts were not executed but treated as output text. I'm not sure I'd call it a bug. if it is "a bug" then the bug is in the extension in that it didn't exclude non-rendered files when it injects its scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it looks like added by Chrome extension. Please take a look on screenshot. Not sure that this extension is eligible. What do you think?

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).